# Using a static Boom Pole

Tags: boom-pole

I have a Manfrotto tripod, Canon T3i and Rode videomic pro. I also have the Rode boom pole, but I was wondering which the best way to use it in an interview situation.

For an interview indoors where the talent is sat down, it would be ideal to have the boom pole fixed (i.e. not being held by an operator), since we have minimal crew (2-3 people depending). That being said, we also want to minimise the amount of gear we carry so my question is this:

- Is it possible/recommended to somehow mount my boom to the tripod (which will also have the camera attached too) AND keep it out of shot?
- Should I buy a separate stand for the boom and if so what kind?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For seated interview subjects I usually put the mic on a standard mic stand, the kind that has a horizontal arm, like this:

[image: mic stand]

usually I have to extend the main pole as far as it will go to get the top pole horizontal so it doesn't cut the corner of the frame.

Having the mic in front of and above the speakers mouth means that you don't get pops and sybilance from them breathing into it, and also lets you get the mic closer—the top of the frame is usually closer to the subject's head than the bottom of frame.

Another option is to get a boom pole holder - like this one:

[image]

That will be a more pricey option as you'll need to buy a [C-stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-Stand) to put it on

Answer (score 2):

I would not attach the boom pole to the camera tripod, because even light forces to the pole may irritate the camera.

I suppose you know that shot gun mics pick up the sound in front, but also from the back. That's why mounting a mic on top of the camera may easily pick up an echo from behind in smaller rooms.

My suggestion would be to buy a small table tripod for the mic and put it right in front of the interviewee, just out of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

An even easier solution is to use a lavalier microphone on the person.

No need to hold anything. The sound quality would probably be better.

Comment: Actually I will be using a lav mic as well, but I like to use two sources of audio whenever possible

Comment: I recommend that approach. Lav mics can get good sound without too much fuss, but I often find that a boom mic gets better sound quality, and you don't have the problem of clothing noise and accidental bumps from the talent. Where a lav mic really is useful is for an interview where the subject isn't static.